# MultiPartMimeStreamFormatException error when importing pbix files using rest-api

Tags: powershell, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

So I'm using powershell to automate my power BI reports into my workspace through imports API.
here's the code which I'm using :

```
    $PBIXuri="my azure blob storage url",
    $Workspaceurl="https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/mygroups/imports?datasetDisplayName=myreportname",
    $AccessToken="my oauth token"

    #download my pbix file from azure blob storage
    $cli = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $exportpbix = $cli.DownloadData($PBIXuri)

    $powerBiBody = @'
    --exptest
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file";
    Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed

    {0}
    --exptest--

    '@

    #set my pbix file into request body
    $encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('iso-8859-1')
    $body = $powerBiBody -f $encoding.GetString($exportpbix)

    $headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer " + $AccessToken}

    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Workspaceurl -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $body -ContentType "multipart/form-data; boundary=--exptest"
```

but it always return an error like :

```
Invoke-RestMethod :     {"error":
     {"code":"MultiPartMimeStreamFormatException","pbi.error": 
       {"code":"MultiPartMimeStreamFormatException",
        "parameters":{},
        "details":[],
        "exceptionCulprit":1
        }
      }
    }
```

where do I went wrong on my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem.
on my request body, the content-type which I set was "application/x-zip-compressed".
while my pbix file is "application/stream-octet", after I change it my files was imported correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To import a file, request Headers should include **Content-Type: multipart/form-data** with the file encoded as form data in the request body, as noted in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/imports/postimportingroup). The request body should look like this:

[image]

See [Upload a local PBIX file using the import API](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/fr-fr/blog/upload-a-local-pbix-file-using-the-import-api/).

Maybe the easiest way is to try to save the downloaded data to a file on disk, let's say in `$filePath`, and add [`-InFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7#parameters) parameter to your your call:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Workspaceurl -Method Post -InFile $filePath -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: Hi, I got a similar issue, can you check it and give me a hint please ? https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/how-to-post-import-pbix-file/m-p/1598191#M27231